# Pushing to git a folder downloaded with svn export

Tags: git, github

I have downloaded a specific folder of a git repository using svn export:

```
 svn export https://github.com/user/repo.git/trunk/doc/myFolder
```

Now I have myFolder folder locally, but after making changes I want to push it to the git repo in the same directory from where I have downloaded it. I also need to include a .gitignore file with the list of files not to be included.

Currently if I type git status inside the downloaded folder it says

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I want that when I push to the repo the files in the folder on git will get replaced with my local version. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you use svn to deal with git. Why don't you clone the repo, make changes, add and commit, and then push... as explained in all git tutorials?

Comment: Assumably `trunk/doc/myFolder` is what the error says "not a Git repository". `https://github.com/user/repo.git/` would be, which if you had `git clone`-d, you'd be fine

Comment: @JBNizet because the repository is large and I only want to make changes to a particular folder, without cloning the entire repo on disk

Comment: Related. http://askubuntu.com/questions/460885/how-to-clone-git-repository-only-some-directories

Comment: You can use --depth to avoid downloading the whole history. Use `git clone --help`. Not using git as it's intended to be used will only get you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The result of an `svn export` command is a simple directory tree without any version control data. You cannot commit in it, not with `git`, not even with `svn`. `svn export` is only suitable if you want to read files of a sub-directory and never intend to commit and push back.

If you want to work with the repository, make changes and push back, you can use the `--depth` option of `git clone`. It takes an integer parameter, and it will clone only the specified number of recent commits of a single branch. It will get all the files of the latest revision, you cannot filter to a specific sub-directory only. So it's not exactly what you want to do, but hey, no pain no gain.